# Excel 0x800A03EC Error

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008-r2, excel-2003, excel-automation

I was getting [UNKNOWN] Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC--ERROR at this line in my Windows Server 2008 which is running Office 2003:

```
excelApp.Workbooks.Open(path, 0, false, 5, "", "", false, 
    Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",true, false, 0, true);
```

I had multiple applications running which generate excel reports. Most of them use

```
Excel._Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
```

All of these applications failed except one application which had

```
ApplicationClass excelApp=new ApplicationClass();
```

So, I updated the first failed application to use `ApplicationClass` instead of `Excel.Application`. That solved the issue and I did not get `0x800A03EC` error anymore on the app.

But to my surprise all the rest of the failed applications are not getting this error anymore. There hasn't been any other change made to the server. I even reverted the change I made on the first application and even it is running fine without the error.

Has anyone experienced this issue? I see that this server does not have Microsoft Excel under DCOM Config in the component services. Is this somehow related?

Comment: Servers and Excel don't really mix.

Comment: Yes, I understand. We will be migrating away to OpenXML in future.

Comment: This is a really generic error code, but there are a couple strong possibilities.  One common case is running the English version of Excel on a machine with the Regional Settings set to a non-english language.

Comment: @Claies I did check the System Locale and Input Locale. They are set to en-us;English <United States>. So no issue with that.